# Java Application connecting to PostgreSQL through Nginx proxying SSL

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, ssl, nginx

I have a java (spring) application running on Tomcat that needs to consume data from a Postgres DB that is proxied by a NGINX. Postgress doesn't use SSL and the connection from the java app to the NGINX should be over SSL.

Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to this address :    /etc/nginx/sites-available
create  api.postgres.com file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name api.postgres.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:5432;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

}

This should route the request towards running instance of postgres that will be running on port 5432.

Make sure your domain api.postgres.com must point to your server on which your database is installed.

I never did that, but I think this should work.

Thanks.

Comment: The nginx has a directive  `listen       8443 ssl;`, it's listening on a secured port, so my doubt is how would be the configuration on the java application side to connect to the DB through that secured proxy.

Comment: Doesn't the OP want the connection to Postgres to use SSL?